# Select2 Not displaying properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

I have a Bootstrap Modal in which I am trying to display a select2 control. The control shows up and it works perfectly well but it doesn't display properly. I have attached a screenshot of how it is rendering as. I also copied and pasted the exact same code to a regular page and that is displaying properly. I inspected the border property as well as various other css properties but am unable to determine why it is displaying like that. Can anyone give me some pointers on how I can solve this issue?

[JsFiddle showing the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/parthsha/aabq9utc/) 
**Note:** Please maximize the width of the result window to see the issue in action.

Html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Country</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select class="js-example-basic-single form-control">
            <option></option>
            <option>Canada</option>
            <option>Mexico</option>
            <option>United States</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
    placeholder: "Select country..."
});
```

[image: Image of rendering issue]

---

**EDIT:**

I would also like to point out there is a dependency to the [select2-bootstrap library](http://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/index.html). If I use just the select2 library, I am *not* witnessing this issue.

Comment: This appears to have something to do with the scrollbar, if you open the developer tools it appears to shift itself over (into the correct spot).

Comment: @KevinBrown I opened developer tools but didn't see the shift happen. I also manually added scrollbar via css onto the modal-body element but didn't see any movement.

Comment: Side note: Select2 4.0.0 is out, if you are in a situation where you can upgrade it's recommended.